# Copy current week entries to a new excel worknook with VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I need to copy data from column A to X for each row that have a current week date in column B from  the active worksheet into another workbook/Sheet1. Since in destination workbook there's already data I need to paste the data in first blank row.

I tried to build the code but I get 424 error.

I'm very new to this and I would like to get some help on this.

```
Sub Copy()
Dim startdate As Date, enddate As Date
Dim rng As Range, destRow As Long
Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Set shtSrc = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set shtDest = Workbooks(Destination).Sheets(Sheet1)
'find next blank row
destRow = Workbooks(Destination).Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
'start copying to this row
startdate = CDate((Date - Weekday(Date, 2) + 1))
enddate = CDate(Date - Weekday(Date, 2) + 7)
'scan for date column, B in my case
Set rng = Application.Intersect(shtSrc.Range("B:B"), shtSrc.UsedRange)
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If c.Value >= startdate And c.Value <= enddate Then
        c.ActiveSheet.Range("A:X").Copy _shtDest.Cells(destRow, 0)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: `ActiveSheet` is not a property of `Range`

Comment: I believe Tim Williams comment above gives the source of your error, and the update in Thomas Inzina's answer shows how to fix it.  But you should also include a `destRow = destRow + 1` statement after your `Copy` statement or else you will be constantly writing to the same destination row.

Answer (score 0):

The underscore is a line break.

> c.ActiveSheet.Range("A:X").Copy `_`shtDest.Cells(destRow, 0)

Either remove it

> c.ActiveSheet.Range("A:X").Copy shtDest.Cells(destRow, 0)

Or use it to break the line and contiuee the rest of the code on the next line

> c.ActiveSheet.Range("A:X").Copy _
>
> shtDest.Cells(destRow, 0)

### Update:

Use `c.EntireRow.Range("A:X")` to copy all the cells in Columns("A:X") on the same row(s) as `c`

`c.EntireRow.Columns("A:X").Copy shtDest.Cells(destRow)`

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks.  I was thinking Columns when I wrote it.  I updated it to ``Columns("A:X")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyAtoX()
    Dim startdate As Date, enddate As Date
    Dim rng As Range, destRow As Long
    Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range
    Set shtSrc = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set shtDest = Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1") '<~~ replace Book1 with the name of your destination WB, dont forget quotes
    'find next blank row
    destRow = shtDest.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    'start copying to this row
    startdate = CDate((Date - Weekday(Date, 2) + 1))
    enddate = CDate(Date - Weekday(Date, 2) + 7)
    'scan for date column, B in my case
    Set rng = shtSrc.UsedRange.Columns("B")
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c.Value >= startdate And c.Value <= enddate Then
            shtSrc.Range("A" & c.Row & ":X" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Cells(destRow, 1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @YowE3K Ahhh, you are right. I need to modify that part.

Answer (score 0):

Since range c is in column B, another way would be:

```
c.Offset(,-1).Resize(,24).Copy _ shtDest.Cells(destRow, 1)
destRow = destRow + 1
```

Or, if you're interested in pasting values only (which is faster):

```
shtDest.Cells(destRow, 1).Resize(,24).Value = c.Offset(,-1).Resize(,24).Value
destRow = destRow + 1
```